Prepositions used with tenses
Prepositions matter.



I will do it for 2 days by Monday




I will have done it for 2 days by Monday



Because we talks about something we will have done for some time by Monday only 2 is correct. Yet, it is enough to change "for" to "in" to make it possible to use future simple and say



I will do it in 2 days by Monday



Is 3 correct without perfect because "in" shows in what time something can be done and "for" indicates that someone have been doing it?


might make sense written as, "I will do it in 2 days, that is, by Monday." Or, "I will do it in 2 days, i.e., by Monday." BTW, none are sentences, without end punctuation.


"we talks about" and " someone have been" ??

The problem with this question is that you have a conflict between two time periods, "two days" and "by Monday".  It only works if today is Saturday. No native English speaker would say any of them, but they might qualify one by adding the other. "I will have it done in two days, that is by Monday" or "I will have it done by Monday which is 2 days time".
